# Is Safari eTag cache implementation broken?

Tags: caching, safari, etag

I have a rest API and I have problems using Safari implementation of the cache. When a `GET` is performed on my resource, eTag is returned. Just after I perform `DELETE` on the same URL and I can see Safari sends eTag with `if-none-match`, so server refuses to delete the resource, as eTags match. Other browsers work just fine.

I have tried disabling cache adding `max-age=0, no-cache, no-store` to all responses in the server, but no luck. Is there any way of avoiding Safari sending eTag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally was working using `Cache-control":"max-age=0, no-cache, no-store"` header, just remove all cookies and sessions before testing